# addEventListener not working in <object> tag in IE10

Tags: javascript, html

**What I Do**
I create an object tag in javascript and append in DOM. I add an click eventListener for that tag.

**The Problem**
Click Event is not working in IE10

My Code:

```
var _pluginObj = document.createElement('object');
var windowlessParam = document.createElement("param");
windowlessParam.setAttribute('name', 'windowless');
windowlessParam.setAttribute('value', true); 

_pluginObj.appendChild(windowlessParam);
_pluginObj.setAttribute('classid', 'CLSID:7FD49E23-C8D7-4C4F-93A1-F7EACFA1EC53');
document.body.appendChild(_pluginObj);
_pluginObj.addEventListener('click', function() {
     console.log("In PeersList");
     // I NEED TO CALL A FUNCTION HERE.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In IE rather [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx) is used, instead of addEventListener.

Use it like:

```
if (_pluginObj.addEventListener){
  _pluginObj.addEventListener('click', modifyText, false); 
} else if (_pluginObj.attachEvent){
  _pluginObj.attachEvent('onclick', modifyText);
}
```

to check if addEventlistener is available and use attachEvent if not.

You can also use jquery framework to easy bind click events.[Jquery Bind Api](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Jquery is doing the browser checks for you.

Comment: addEventListener works in IE10. attachEvent is for IE<9

Comment: i thought so, too. But as he mentioned, his code is not working in IE10 but seams correct to me.

Comment: Behaviour seems to be different (in IE10) if you're viewing a page in Compatibility Mode.  window.addEventListener is undefined if you are.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery

```
$(_pluginObj).click(function() {
   console.log("In PeersList");
});
```

You can also use jQuery for the creation of the element.

Comment: How does this fix his addEventListener issue? He's not using jQuery, either.

Comment: Adding jQuery to a non-jQuery problem is not a solution to a vanilla javascript problem.

Comment: @Rob: Where is the pre-condition about jQuery? I thought that the meaning of this is to provide solutions not criticize other

Comment: The question is about addEventListener in javascript. Your answer is to use a library and different code instead. So your answer does not apply to the problem or question asked.